# How to obtain the prediction for training and test set in each cross validation fold in random forest model generated by Caret package of R

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction, cross-validation, caret

I have generated a Random forest model (model1) by 5 fold cross validation in R (793 total samples). I am able to obtain the training set prediction of each fold of 5 cross validating in random forest model generated by CARET in R by saving the model1$pred in a separate table followed by subsetting this table it by fold wise. However, I am unable to obtain the prediction of rest of the samples in cross validation. Any leads for how to obtain the prediction for the samples not in the training set in each fold of cross validation? basically for the sample present in model1$control$index?
code:
``For generating the model

```
set.seed(123)
folds <- createFolds(bc_data$classes, k=5)
train_control <- trainControl( method="cv", number=5,index=folds, classProbs = TRUE, savePredictions = "final", returnResamp='all')
model1 <- train(classes~.,  data=(train_data[,-1]), trControl=train_control, method="rf",metric="Accuracy", preProcess=c("center","scale"))

# Warning in preProcess.default(thresh = 0.95, k = 5, freqCut = 19, uniqueCut = 10,  :
#   These variables have zero variances: mindNH
# Warning in preProcess.default(thresh = 0.95, k = 5, freqCut = 19, uniqueCut = 10,  :
#   These variables have zero variances: mindNH
# Warning in preProcess.default(thresh = 0.95, k = 5, freqCut = 19, uniqueCut = 10,  :
#   These variables have zero variances: mindNH

print(model1)

# Random Forest 
# 
# 793 samples
#  70 predictor
#   2 classes: 'Active', 'Inactive' 
# 
# Pre-processing: centered (70), scaled (70) 
# Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
# 
# **Summary of sample sizes: 158, 158, 160, 159, 158** 
# 
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:
# 
#   mtry  Accuracy   Kappa    
#    2    0.7701729  0.5345031
#   36    0.7679617  0.5303971
#   70    0.7626059  0.5195646

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

So, basically I want to obtain the results for the samples not used in training in each fold of cross validation. I am only able to obtain the predication of 693 sample by following code:

```
model1_result <- model1$pred
first_holdout_model1 <- subset(model1_result, model1_result$Resample == "Fold1")
```

This only gives the predictions of 693 samples, how to obtain the predictions for rest 158 samples for each fold?

Comment: Please format your code using backticks (`) not quote blocks (>),

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Much appreciated.  This is my first question. I don't know about the aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run `folds <- createFolds(bc_data$classes, k = 5, returnTrain = TRUE)` instead.

`trainControl(index = )` wants the indices of the training rows, not the validation rows.

Ultimately, `model$pred` should contain the same number of rows as the original data set.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur. Yes, the model$pred contains the same number of rows and its for the final predictions. Here, I want to access the results of the each fold of cross validation. So ideally in each cross validation, there should be prediction for all the samples and I want to obtain the predication for 793 samples in each fold of 5 CV. With your code, now the `first_holdout_model1 <- subset(model1_result, model1_result$Resample == "Fold1")`           gives the prediction of 158 samples. However,  want the predictions of 793 samples for Fold1. Help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is for "the prediction for the samples not in the training set in each fold of cross validation".  These are in `model$pred`.  So I think this is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much Arthur. I got it now.